# Why is present perfect used with specific date in this sentence?

Tags: present-perfect

As far as I know, it is an absolute rule that present perfect is not used with specific date. However, I saw this sentence in the beginning of a video in [this TIME article](http://time.com/5436877/trump-synagogue-armed-guard/):

> 11 people have died in a shooting at a synagogue in Pittsburgh on Oct. 27, authorities said.

I have two reasons for this usage:

- It is a custom in news/journalism.
- The shooting occurred on Oct. 27, but 11 people have died *so far*.

Am I correct?

Comment: On a specific date but not at a specific time.

Answer (score 2):

The shooting occurred at a specific time, but the action described by the present perfect is not limited to that specific time. The people may have died after the shooting from their injuries. Also, some people may die days or weeks after the violent event, so the use of present perfect indicates that the number of people who have died is the current total. Use of the simple past tense would imply that the number was a final total.

So the present perfect expresses both that the people who have died may not have died exactly at the time of the event and that more people may end up dying.